ListView List.add is delayed until an update of the activity
I defined a unique simple Activity. In the middle of the layout I added a ListView which seems to be the solution for scroll lists.
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/editPinCode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textConnect"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:background="#1A4C3737" />

Here is the definition of the ListView and the necessary types for the binding :
    public ListView listView;
    public List list = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayAdapter adapter;

Here is the initialization code in the OnCreate method :
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(A6ServiceActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Here is the code of the function that adds an element in the list :
void newSession(String device, String appid) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.v(tag,"newSession");
            list.add("signed "+new Date().toString()+" "+device+" "+appid);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()   // HERE ADDED
        }
    });
}

The behavior is very strange, the item is not added immediately. The item appears when a new item is added to the list. So, I'm wondering if there is some kind of commit necessary to refresh the structure.
I think that it is a bug of mine, I do not consider using another structure.
Thanks for help

Just need to add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); immediately after list.add()

Perfect, thank you
